# escaping dot in Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have been using tuckey Apache mod-rewrite engine to rewrite urls. But I have problems in escaping dots to decorate URLS as shown below,

```
www.example.com/hello.world -> www.example.com/derive.php
```

Following rules are the ones I have written to do the above thing,

```
RewriteRule ^/?(([A-Za-z0-9:-])+([.]*))$ /derive.php[L]
```

(`RewriteRule ^/?(([A-Za-z0-9:-\.])+)$ /derive.php[L]` is not allowed by tuckey)

I think this question can be answered perfectly by people those who have used tuckey to decorate URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a character class, dots don't have any special meaning, so it shouldn't be necessary to escape them; you should be able to write simply:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!/?derive[.]php$)/?[A-Za-z0-9:.-]+$ /derive.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Ruakh,
Still I could not get it to work. Your solution gave me a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Like I mentioned above, I am using tuckey mod_rewrite engine in a GAE application. Apparently it does not support all mod_rewrite options.

Anyone got a work around for this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: @ChamikaDilshan: I suspect that's because of infinite recursion -- `/derive.php` itself matches this rule, so it recurses infinitely. (`[L]` is supposed to prevent that, but maybe Tuckey doesn't support it very well?) So I've modified the regex to specifically exclude `derive.php` in applying this rule.

Comment: Actually I am new to URL decorating. However I was able to simplify all rules in to a single rule with your perfect directions.