# Safely escape period/dot (.) character in .htaccess mod_rewrite regex

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` file that is used by an advanced SEO URL php system installed on my osCommerce site.

It has the following rules that work just fine for most cases, but removing periods from my GET parameters:

```
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

So URL like this:

```
http://example.com//index.php?cPath=44_95&page=1&range=1.99_2.99
```

gets rewritten according to the rule and the `1.99_2.99` becomes `199_299`.

How can I escape the period safely? (ie. without causing some random side effects)

Comment: Use a character class `[.]`

Comment: @stribizhev thanks, but how do I add it to my rules? I am a complete noob  with regex...

Comment: I think what you asked is related to unescaped dot in your patterns. If you are unsure of whether to use 1 backslash or two, use a character class. Replace `.html` with `[.]html`. However, I am not sure that is all you need.

Comment: You only need to use a single backslash `\.`

Comment: Your rewrites don't match your sample URL, and they don't strip the "." character.  You're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard escape character for .htaccess regular expressions is the slash ("`\`").

```
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-c-([0-9_]+)\.html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
                                        ^^
  RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-m-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
                                       ^^
```

The slash will prevent the meaning of the dot and escape it so that the dot is taken verbatim as a character to match (period, ASCII code 46 / x2E) .

The other suggestion given in the comment to create a character class consisting of the dot only ("`[.]`") does the job as well, but it's perhaps a bit over the top to create a character class while you only want to name a single character. But it's technically working (and has been suggested for example in [escaping dot in Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646792/367456)).

BTW: [Apache rewrite uses Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) which is the same flavour of regex like PHP is using in the `preg_*` family of functions which is PHP's preferred regex dialect.